# Request PR review from team via CLI

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

GitHub's API has an endpoint to [request reviewers for a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/pulls#request-reviewers-for-a-pull-request). Reviewers can be individual users (`reviewers`) or entire [teams](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/about-teams) (`team_reviewers`) (teams can be created at the org level).

For instance, the following will request a PR review from Stack Overflow's `SRE` team:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/StackExchange/dnscontrol/pulls/930/requested_reviewers \
  -d '{"team_reviewers":["SRE"]}'
```

Similarly, in GitHub's [CLI](https://cli.github.com), the [gh pr create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) command to create a pull request has a `--reviewer` flag, equivalent to the `reviewers` API parameter. So, as stated in the documentation, you can do the following to request a PR review from individual users:

```
$ gh pr create --reviewer monalisa,hubot
```

However, there doesn't appear to be a flag which is equivalent to the `team_reviewers` API parameter.

Is it possible to request a PR review from a team via the GitHub CLI?

**UPDATE** looking at the [source](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/9a20719ec4ad6673b34edd615d5f6ba3a94828f3/pkg/cmd/pr/shared/params.go#L94) of the CLI, `--reviewer` should just accept team names in the format `org/teamname`. I was just able to confirm it locally, but it's failing in a GitHub Actions workflow. Digging more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the API, the CLI doesn't have a separate parameter. `--reviewer` just accepts team names in the format `org/teamname` as well. For example:

```
$ gh pr create --reviewer stackexchange/sre
```

([PR](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/2465) to document this a little better)

Note that when doing this in GitHub Actions workflow, [`GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#permissions-for-the-github_token) won't have enough permissions to request a PR review from a team. You'll have to use a personal access token with additional permissions.

Comment: Hey Max! Can you please clarify which permissions do I need to provide to the PAT for it to be able to assign reviewers? Thank you!

Comment: I believe the token had to have just the "repo" scope (Full control of private repositories).